# How to automatically scale Heroku Java backend dynos?

Tags: java, heroku, jetty, grizzly, autoscaling

I'm prototyping a cloud backend using Java that consists of web and worker dynos (a RESTful service).  Now that I'm close to completion, I'm wondering if there's an auto scaler for the web and worker dynos.  I see that there's HireFire and Hero Scale, but those are targeted towards Ruby running on Sinatra or Rails.

For worker dynos I think I can try to find out the queue capacity (I use AMQP RabbitMQ) and scale accordingly, but I'm a little unsure of how to scale the web dynos (Jersey on Jetty via Grizzly).  Is there a way to look at average http response times across all requests over all web dynos?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [HeroScale](http://heroscale.com/), they might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Do you happen to know if they support AMQP and Java?  I tried emailing them, but got no response.

Answer (score 0):

http://scaledynos.herokuapp.com works for all Heroku worker and dynos, no matter what language